# Using distinct and sum in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get the `SUM(Values)` for each Acct, but my issue is trying to get at least one entire row for a `DISTINCT` Acct with the `SUM(Values)`.

I have some sample data for example:

```
Acct         Values    Name       Street     
123456789    100.20    John       66 Main Street
123456789    200.80    John       22 Main Avenue
222222222    50.25     Jane       1 Blvd
333333333    25.00     Joe        55 Test Ave
333333333    50.00     Joe        8 Douglas Road
555555555    75.00     Tim        12 Clark Ave
666666666    500.00    Tim        12 Clark Street
666666666    500.00    Tim        3 Main Rd.
```

My query consisted of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Acct, SUM(Value) AS [TOTAL]
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Acct
```

The above query gets me close to what I need, but I need the entire row.

Example below of what I am looking for:

```
Acct         Total      Name       Addr1     
123456789    301.00     John       66 Main Street 
222222222    50.25      Jane       1 Blvd
333333333    75.00      Joe        55 Test Ave
555555555    75.00      Tim        12 Clark Ave
666666666    1000.00    Tim        12 Clark Street
```

Thanks.

Comment: `acct = 666666666` has two addresses, which one do you want?

Comment: I'd like the first row for each acct.

Comment: But what identifies the first row, do you have an id column or a datetime?  Data in a table is not inherently ordered, you have to provide the order that you want the data to be return in.

Answer (score 4):

If it does not matter what address you return, then you can apply and aggregate to the other columns:

```
SELECT Acct, 
  SUM(Value) AS [TOTAL], 
  max(name) name, 
  max(Street) addr1
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Acct;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dabbf/7)

Comment: Also if this answer is "Perfect" you may want to consider UpVoting/accepting it.

Comment: As long as the record is associated with that particular account number. So if the account has multiple rows of addresses, then just give me one of those.

Comment: @dolm777 . . . This gives you one of the addresses and one of the names.  However, they may not be on the same row.  Your question suggests that you want them on the same row ("The above query gets me close to what I need, but I need the entire row").

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using window functions such as `row_number()` in most databases:

```
select acct, total, name, addr1
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by acct order by acct) as seqnum,
             sum(value) over (partition by acct) as Total
      from table_name
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use Windowing Functions (the OVER clause) to solve this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   Acct
  ,SUM([Values]) OVER (PARTITION BY Acct) AS 'Total'
  ,Name
  ,FIRST_VALUE(Street) OVER (PARTITION BY Acct ORDER BY Street DESC) AS 'Addr1'
  FROM TABLE_NAME
;
```

The nice thing about Windowing Functions is that you do not add things to a grouping that you do not need in your functions (e.g. SUM), instead you can focus on describing what you are looking for.

In the SQL above, we are saying we want the SUM of Values grouped by (or PARTITION BY as it is called in the OVER clause) Acct.  The FIRST_VALUE allows use to return the first value of the street address.  The same did not have a DATETIME column so it is hard to say what the order should be for the first value.  There is also a LAST_VALUE windowing function.  Assuming you do have a DATETIME column you would want to ORDER BY that column value, if not you can just pick some value like I did with Street (MAX might also be a good option then too, but having some type of DATETIME value would be the best way to do it).

Check out this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a474c/8

Here is the BOL about SUM using the OVER clause: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx

Here is more info on FIRST_VALUE: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/09/sql-server-introduction-to-first-_value-and-last_value-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Here is a blog post I've done on the Windowing Functions: http://comp-phil.blogspot.com/2013/03/higher-order-functions.html